# Source control for Visual Studio gets switched from TFVC to Git unprompted

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

After making sure my source control in VS was set to Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC), I connected to a team project, double clicked the solution in Source Control Explorer, and hit "yes" on the notification to bind the project.  Once I did that, I saw that my Source control option got switched back to Git automatically. When I try switching once more to TFVC, the project closes because it was previously linked to git. My instructor says that we are always supposed to stay on TFVC. She mentioned that unprompted switching between the two is an issue some people have, though she is unsure why.  I'm wondering if anyone here has encountered this, and might have any ideas on how to fix it?  It just seems to be going in circles.  I'm using VS 2017 Community, in case that detail is relevant.

This screenshot is part of my reply to Jesse, regarding the .git folder that must be deleted.  When I navigate to the project folder, I see several possible locations where it might be, but cannot locate it.[image: My project folder]  The team project is the one called "JobPlacementDashBoard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project folder, there is a `.git` folder. Visual Studio automatically detects this and switches over to the Git provider.

To fix:

- Close Visual Studio
- Delete the `.git` folder
- Start Visual Studio again
- In Options switch back to TFVC

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, Jesse!  I looked inside the project folder to find .git, but was unable to locate it.  Just to clarify, by "project folder," you mean the version of the team project folder that is saved to my work space, or do you mean the work space folder itself? I searched both, but .git wasn't there.  I will edit my post with a screenie of what I see when I navigate to the project folder. Is it generally in the same place for everyone? Thanks again!!

Comment: It looks like you are not showing hidden files in explorer. The .git folder is usually marked as hidden so that's probably why you don't see it. Maybe try looking for JobPlacementDashboard\JobPlacementDashboard\.git

Comment: You can execute this from the commandline from inside any folder in the repository to find the folder: `git rev-parse --git-dir`

Comment: Thank you both!  I was not able to find a .git folder for that repo, even after I tried showing all hidden folders and searching with the commandline   My instructor said it could be that I have other .git folders in other locations that are causing the issue, so I'm going through and deleting those to see if it helps.  Your suggestions have helped me to uncover those other .git folders, and I appreciate it!